# SEO Friendly exposed filter view

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view, with few exposed filter in it. It is working fine, but I when I filter view using some exposed filter, it appends query string to URL ie

```
mysite.com/search?field1=value_1&field_2=value2
```

Instead I wanted to make it SEO friendly like,

```
mysite.com/search/value_1/value2
```

Please guide how should I proceed. I have searched for it, but didn't get any solution or I have missed something.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think this may be merge-worthy into the question I marked this a duplicate of.